# If I Don't Wire USBASP to ATmega 328-PU Will I Burn Out My Chip

Tags: avr, atmega, usbasp

This is a simple, noob question. I'm trying to connect a USBASP with an ATmega 328-PU. If I incorrectly connect them, such as put ground into vcc or miso into mosi, will I kill my chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is quite possible, so do not miswire it.

What you could do is try to defend the chip from yourself. For example, you could put some resistors, say 220 ohm, on the MISO, MOSI and CLK lines. This will give you some safety from bad connections.

Of course, this won't help you if you connect GND to Vcc, since you can't have resistors on those two lines.

If you have any doubt, use a multimeter. If you get to the point where you're not sure what you're doing, make a break and try it in 20 minutes or next day or whenever you're a bit more rested.

Comment: From his latest schematic it seems you can actually put resistors with a reverse diode in the power supply lines, provided you do not power your board from the USBASP.

Comment: Ok, but whose latest schematic?

Comment: The USBASP guy: http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/

Comment: Thanks AndrejaKo. I should have used the multimeter. I probably reversed ground and vcc and nuked the chip

Comment: Would reversing ground and vcc only kill the ATmega 328 or would it kill the USBASP, as well?

Comment: @Laxmidi That depends on what exactly you reverse. If you tie MOSI (master out, slave in) to ground, that had the probability to damage the programmer. If you tie MISO (master in, slave out), that has the probability of damaging the ATmega. Basically, what you need to keep in mind is that the IN ports should be in high-impedance state, so they should be safe. The out ports will output voltage and if the input impedance is too low, the excessive current might kill the pin or port.